# Word for people in favour of climate change

Tags: single-word-request

There are:

- *Klimaschützer, Klimaaktivisten* – people against climate change,
- *Klimawandel-Leugner, Klimawandel-Skeptiker* – people with the opinion, that either there is no climate change at all or that climate is not influenced by humans.

And then there are people who voice the opinion that climate change is great and advantageous for each and everyone and should be endorsed. What is the term for the last mentioned group of people? There might be regions on Earth, where local effects of climate change really might be advantageous, but I am looking for a term for people who consider it great for mankind as a whole.

What is the German (non-derogative) term for this group? *Klimawandel-Befürworter* would convey the meaning, but I have read that nowhere.

Comment: I've never heard of such people, at least not in Germany. Just out of curiosity - how do you call them in English?

Comment: There are _Profiteure_ oder _Nutznießer des Klimawandels_, but it's not exactly what you described (at least in the original version of your question before editing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word in use is the rather plainly clad *Klimawandel-Befürworter*.

[Search engines](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22klimawandel-bef%C3%BCrworter%22&t=hk&ia=web) [confirm](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22klimawandel-bef%C3%BCrworter%22) the non-exotic use for it.

It now even seems to have an abbreviation: KWB:

> Die Klimawandel-Leugner (KWL) stehen den Klimawandel-Befürwortern (KWB) mit ihren Argumenten unversöhnlich gegenüber. Dem kritischen Bürger werden die wichtigsten Positionen präsentiert und er möge entscheiden welche Seite glaubhafter ist.
>   <sub>[Karl-Heinz Hinrichs: "Der Klimawandel: Bedrohung der Menschheit", 6. März 2018](http://www.evalww.com/der-klimawandel-bedrohung-der-menschheit/)</sub>
>
> Auch in Deutschland trat am vergangenen Wochenende das Phänomen der Klimawandel-Befürworter auf. Nach Angaben von FAZ-Online fordert der konservative Berliner Kreis innerhalb der CDU in einer Erklärung das Ende der „moralischen Erpressung“ durch den Klimaschutz. Die Ziele des Pariser Abkommens seien ohnehin nicht erreichbar und die deutsche Politik solle sich an die neuen Gegebenheiten, die durch den Klimawandel entstehen, anpassen. Man solle weniger negativ auf die Folgen des Klimawandels blicken. Auch die Gruppe von CDU-Politkern erkennt Vorteile, wenn das Meereis schmilzt: Neben den Rohstoffen, die unter Eisplatten zum Vorschein kommen, sehen sie auch neue Fischfangmöglichkeiten und Handelsrouten, wenn die riesigen Platten aus Meereis verschwinden.
>   <sub>[Ja zum Klimawandel: Ein neuer Trend?](http://www.pflichtlektuere.com/07/06/2017/ja-zum-klimawandel-ein-neuer-trend/)</sub>

One problem here is that some people use that word as describing just accepting the existing explanation of "climate change is real" (but are against an uncontrolled changed in that direction, quote 1)
and that some use it to describe people who accept this explanation and welcome the results (quote2).

Given the primitive analysis of word parts, I'd say that case 1 should properly be called *menschengemachter Klimawandeltheorieakzeptierende*?

*Klimawandelbefürworter* read literally would be climate change fans.

As the whole concept is most widely seen made by climate-change-(treatment)-'skeptics' who use this line of argument:

> [Personen, die auf diesen PR-Trick setzen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anpassung_an_die_globale_Erw%C3%A4rmung#Anpassung_als_Argumentationsmuster_von_Klimaschutzgegnern), stellen sich dabei zunächst als vernünftige Interpreten der wissenschaftlichen Erkenntnisse dar, argumentieren dann aber, dass wir uns an die Erwärmung anpassen sollten, dass die Erwärmung möglicherweise sogar positiv sei oder dass Klimaschutzmaßnahmen und wirtschaftliche Entwicklung ausgeglichen werden müssten.

Another option might be seen to call these people *Klimawandel-Anpasser* or in another take perhaps *Klimawandel-Apologeten*.

The most problematic dynamic with all these suggestions is that once you know the concepts meant or described by them they will for most quickly change in tone from "(non-derogative)" to negatively connotated.

Comment: I had thought "Klimawandel-Befürworter" to be too exotic to be really used, and therefore I did not even try to find it in the internet. My mistake! Thanks, +1, and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced, that the question is a precise one:

To be in favour of climate change implies some sort of endorsement (and this then translates to *...-Befürworter*). This can be easily recognized when comparing it to *Befürworter einer bedingungslosen Grundrente*, which implies a positive attitude, possibly also resulting in actions. I don't recognize this is in the question.

What is asked for, is simply *not to deny (human-caused) climate change* and this is neither *in favour of* in English nor *Befürworter* in German.

The closest counterpiece I can come up with is

> Klimawandel-Gläubige

which has a probably undesired religious touch (but may seem an even better match for the adversaries). On the other hand the fact, that only the human contribution should be concerned remains unreflected und is not insertable easily. The word would become too long anyway: *Klimawandel* is already a composite noun and glueing several additional nouns to it will lead to result between ugly and impractical.

Summary: I don't see an existing single word for it, but it is possible the *Klimawandelbefürworter* gets the established noun for it despite the poor argumentation.

Comment: "implies a positive attitude, possibly also resulting in actions" - yes, I was looking for this.

Answer (score -2):

"Klimawandel", climate change is something what is happening, constantly, a fact. I don't think in this context the German language gives you a possibility to be in favor ("`Klimawandel-Befürworter`") or against these changes ("`Klimawandel-Gegner`"), as mankind doesn't control climate, just influences it. The words "`Erdbeben-Befürworter`" und "`Erdbeben-Gegner`" would be another even clearer example on how that doesn't make sense.

Maybe that's the reason you didn't find any conclusive reading about it.

In a similar context there are "`Atomstrombefürworter`" and "`Atomstromgegner`", but atomic energy is man-made and therefore you can be in favor or against it.

**note: this is an answer to the Original Question "Word for Klima-Wandel-Befürworter"**, which was edited in the meantime to "Word for people in favor of climate change"

**edit:** in order to answer this question I'd suggest the use of

> Klimaschutzbefürworter or Klimaschutzgegner

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question. It is just speculation why the desired term is difficult to find. (By the way, the general consensus is that mankind *does* influence the climate.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I wrote"mankind doesn't control climate, just influences it"

Comment: Okay, I missed that. Still, as long as there is an influence, the distinction makes sense and there is little difference to nuclear energy.

Comment: It certainly doesn't answer the question of how people who actually think climate change is a good thing are called in German. And as @Wrzlprmft says, if humankind influences the climate change, people can be against it or favour it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis the answer is: "I don't think in this context the German language gives you a possibility to be in favor..." You don't know in which direction climate changes go, how can you be in favor or against it, that's my point

Comment: @Vickel: Of course we know in which general direction climate change is going, especially through the influence of humans. And apparently some people think this is a good thing, while other don't, so yes, people most definitely have a possibility to be in favour of it or against it. Actually, people can even have an opinion on the weather, which is really something they can't influence. I personaly have a strong opinion against snow.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis maybe, but I'm a native German speaker and have a really strange feeling when reading Klimawandel-Befürworter. Anyway, in the meantime the question got edited in a way, that my (the very first) answer loks a bit out of context. The original question title was: Word for "Klima-Wandel-Befürworter ?"